# Prevent grid view recycling for neighbouring items

Tags: android, android-gridview

Using a `GridView`, is it possible to allow the item directly above and below all the visible items to remain in memory? (I have one column in my grid view)

I would like my adapter to prevent recycling for those items as long as they are direct neighbours to items that are currently visible.

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html and try to adapt it to your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that my GridView had some padding on both left and right side. This made the neighbouring items invisible/recycled "too fast".

Removing the padding resolved my issue.